# Changing memory address stored in a variable in C

Tags: c, memory-management, buffer

I have the following `C` program and I would like to change the variable `secret` by changing the memory address. Can you please show me with an example, what I should put for the following two input to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appriciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

unsigned secret = 0xdeadbeef;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    unsigned *ptr;
    unsigned value;


    printf("Welcome! I will grant you one arbitrary write!\n");
    printf("Where do you want to write to? ");
    scanf("%p", &ptr);
    printf("Okay! What do you want to write there? ");
    scanf("%p", (void **)&value);

    printf("Writing %p to %p...\n", (void *)value, (void *)ptr);
    *ptr = value;
    printf("Value written!\n");

    if (secret == 0x1337beef){
        printf("Woah! You changed my secret!\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("My secret is still safe! Sorry.\n");
}
```

If you can, please show me with an example

Comment: this line: scanf("%p", (void **)&value);  is casting the address of value as a void**.  scanf only cares about the address and about the format conversion, so the (void**) is useless

Comment: writing to some user supplied address(some random address) is a good way to crash the program, probably with a seg fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `printf("Address of secret is: %p", &secret);` above anything else, then when you run the program, give the first input the actual address it printed out (&secret), and for the second input give the program "1337beef". For example, on my machine, it stated that the variable secret is located at 0x804a02c, so for the first input I gave it "804a02c" and for the second "1337beef" so it enters the if statement. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Make a variation that prints the address of `secret`. Compile and run the variant program.

*Edit:* The details of addresses and allocations are implementation-specific. So there's no way to discover this number just from the C standard. The value returned by `printf("%p",...` (and affected by `scanf("%p",...`) is dependant upon the specific OS, and the particular setup of the compiler. For example, I have two versions of `gcc` on my Windows machine, one under Cygwin and one under MinGW. And it would be very surprising if `printf("%p",some_static_variable)` printed the same value in both environments.